# Blender 2.75 lmage texture painting. Painted image will not bake

Tags: texturing

I'm fairly new to blender. When I load up my texture image in the texture properties panel the image cover my entire 
model. I can paint over it the way I want but when I try to
bake my painted image it only will bake the image I painted
over. What a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the painted texture first and then load it into the material to be able to bake it onto the new texture.

Comment: Thank you Denis! I was stuck on this for 2 days. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

There is not exactly a baking process involved if you paint your texture. If you are done with painting just go to the image editor's menu, chose "Image" and then "save Image" or "save as Image" if you want to keep the original.